# Entity Framework Core migration issue with dynamic connection string depending on header value and another DB

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core API and trying to automate the stored procedure maintenance through the EF Core migration. The issue is I have 2 databases, `DB1` (`AVMRouterContext`) and `DB2`.

Each API call expects the user name in the header. With this username we search in `DB1` and find the user related information and find the connection string for `DB2`. I want to create a stored procedure through migration in `DB2` but I do  not have connection string until the user calls the API.

Also I am not able to create migration in the code just because of this situation. In app setting I have only the `DB1` connection string.

How do I manage the migration for `DB2`? Help with this issue will be much appreciated.

I have this code

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var result = _vehicleRepo.GetVehicleDetails();
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<AVMRouterContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(RouterConnectionString));
```

In the VehicleRepo class

```
public VehicleRepo(
        ILogger<VehicleRepo> logger,
        IDbContextFactory factory,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IClientRepo clientRepo, 
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // I am getting the username from header
        _userName = Utility.GetUsernameFromHttpContext(httpContextAccessor);             

        // here  I am creating the DB2 context
        _dbContext = factory.GetContext(_userName); 
 
        _ClientRepo = clientRepo;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Response GetVehicleDetails()
    {
         // some code to call SP in DB
         // _dbContext.VehicleDetailsTable.FromSqlRaw("storedProcedure");
    }
}
```

`IDBContextFactory` class to generate db2 context:

```
public class DbContextFactory: IDbContextFactory
{
    public DbContextFactory(IClientRepo clientRepo, IConfiguration configuration,
        ILogger<DbContextFactory> logger)
    {
        ConnectionPool = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DBContainer>();
        _clientRepo = clientRepo;
        Configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    private readonly ILogger<DbContextFactory> _logger;
    private readonly IClientRepo _clientRepo;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, DBContainer> ConnectionPool { get; set; }

    public DBContainer GetContext(string userName)
    {
        if (ConnectionPool.TryGetValue(userName, out DBContainer context))
        {
            return context;
        }

        // get connection string for userName
        var userConnStr = _clientRepo.GetUserConnectionString(userName);

        int timeoutdb = 10;
        
        // create context options based on connection string.
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContainer>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(userConnStr,
            opts => opts.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeoutdb).TotalSeconds));

        // get DBContainer for userName.
        var newContext = new DBContainer(optionsBuilder.Options);
                    
        // store DBContainer in dictionary to reuse.
        ConnectionPool.TryAdd(userName, newContext);

        return newContext;
    }
}
```